# Did Ramanuja compose any devotional works?

Tags: bhakti, ramanujacharya

I am not aware of any - and given his advocacy of devotion and surrender, it would be surprising if he did not compose any.

So - what are some of his devotional works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Sripad Ramanujacharya composed a total of three devotional works, which are collectively known as "Gadyatrayam works":

1) **Sharanagati Gadyam**, which espouses surrender to Sriman Narayana's lotus feet. You can read it [**here**](https://www.prapatti.com/slokas/english/saranaagatigadyam.pdf).

2) **Sri Ranga Gadyam**, which is a devotional work describing the auspicious qualities of Sri Ranganatha (Sriman Narayana). You can read it [**here**](http://www.angelfire.com/ok5/livermore/pdf/Sri_Ranga_Gadyam.pdf).

3) **Sri Vaikuntha Gadyam**, which is a devotional work describing Paramapadam and the position of liberated souls. You can read it [**here**](https://www.prapatti.com/slokas/english/vaikunthagadyam.pdf).

Comment: Here is Sudarshana Suri's commentary on the Sharanagati Gadyam: https://archive.org/details/SaranaGatiGadyaRamnujaTransBhashyamK.Ed.UttamurViraRaghavacharya And here is Periyavachan Pillai's commentary on the Gadyatrayam: http://archive.org/details/periyavachangadyatraya